# how to fix this error DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState on ios

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

**I can not run ios **
This below is error :

```
Launching lib/main_dev.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
main_dev.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            7.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.718 xcodebuild[9606:71296] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Enabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=enabled)
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.719 xcodebuild[9606:71296] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (inserting): added = {(
        <DVTiOSDevicePlaceholder: 0x11a7a5a10 (Any watchOS Device | undefined_arch)>,
        <DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder: 0x11a7f2190 (Any watchOS Simulator Device | undefined_arch)>,
    <DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder: 0x11a7f2680 (Any iOS Simulator Device | undefined_arch)>,
        <DVTiPhonePlaceholder: 0x11a7f2910 (Any iOS Device | undefined_arch)>,
        <DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder: 0x11a7f2040 (Any tvOS Simulator Device | undefined_arch)>,
        <DVTiOSDevicePlaceholder: 0x11a7f22e0 (Any tvOS Device | undefined_arch)>
    )} removed = (null)
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.720 xcodebuild[9606:71296] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (inserting): added = {(
    )} removed = (null)
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.721 xcodebuild[9606:71296] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (inserting): added = {(
        <DVTiOSDevice (0x11a8b03f0), iPad (2), iPad, 14.7.1 (18G82), d2b75ee793c03731cbaee438b9cd8c99118ad213> {
            deviceSerialNumber:         DMPS6QW8G5W0
            identifier:                 d2b75ee793c03731cbaee438b9cd8c99118ad213
            deviceClass:                iPad
            deviceName:                 iPad (2)
            deviceIdentifier:           d2b75ee793c03731cbaee438b9cd8c99118ad213
            productVersion:             14.7.1
            thinningProductType:        (null)
            buildVersion:               18G82
            deviceSoftwareVersion:      14.7.1 (18G82)
            deviceArchitecture:         arm64
            deviceTotalCapacity:        52545560576
            deviceAvailableCapacity:    46003093504
            deviceIsTransient:          NO
            ignored:                    NO
            deviceIsBusy:               NO
            deviceIsPaired:             YES
            deviceIsActivated:          YES
            deviceActivationState:      Activated
            isPasscodeLocked:           NO
            deviceType:                 <DVTDeviceType:0x11a8b0b70 Xcode.DeviceType.iPhone>
            supportedDeviceFamilies:    (null)
            applications:              (null)
            provisioningProfiles:      (null)
            hasInternalSupport:        NO
            hasWritableSystem:         NO
            isSupportedOS:             YES
            bootArgs:                  (null)
            nextBootArgs:              (null)
            connected:                 NO
            isWirelessEnabled:         NO
            connectionType:            direct
            hostname:                  (null)
            bonjourServiceName:        ec:ad:b8:6a:74:1b@fe80::eead:b8ff:fe6a:741b._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.
            activeProxiedDevice:       (null)
            }
    )} removed = (null)
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.722 xcodebuild[9606:71296] [MT] DVTDevice: DVTDeviceStateManager: Began managing new device with identifier d2b75ee793c03731cbaee438b9cd8c99118ad213-mobiledevice
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.722 xcodebuild[9606:71296] [MT] DVTDevice: DVTDeviceStateManager: Notified of new state (0) for device identifier d2b75ee793c03731cbaee438b9cd8c99118ad213-mobiledevice
    2024-01-11 10:19:48.722 xcodebuild[9606:71296] [MT] iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x11a8b03f0), iPad (2), iPad, 14.7.1 (18G82), d2b75ee793c03731cbaee438b9cd8c99118ad213> ################ HAS CONNECTED ###################
```